# Can anyone tell me why my table field reference not work with this trigger query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have a problem formatting an update trigger for my **sqlite** project.
The project has 2 tables. One table is called `Equipment` and has 3 fields:

```
 - UnitID
 - Last_PMI
 - Preset_Hrs
```

The other table is called `ESPModules` and it has 3 fields as well:

```
 - UnitID (FK)
 - ESPModuleID
 - Install_Date
```

I have set up an update trigger on the `ESPModules` table that triggers every time I change the `UnitID` field in the `ESPModules` table. The `UnitID` field has a one-to-one relationship with the Equipment table. (Both tables allow only one unique `UnitID`)

My trigger actually fires but I do not know how to reference the `UnitID` field in my `ESPModules` table. Below is what I have so far and this code does update the Equipment record when it fires:

```
UPDATE Equipment
SET Last_PMI = date('now'),
Preset_Hrs = 0
WHERE UnitID = "BT-109F"


UPDATE Equipment
SET Last_PMI = date('now'),
Preset_Hrs = 0
WHERE UnitID = ESPModules.UnitID;
```

But the problem is I need to reference my `ESPModules.UnitID` field as above: (In other words, as an example, when I type in an existing `UnitID` like "BT-109F", it does fire but does not work when I try to reference the field I am updating and saving. It throws this error: “ An error occurred while committing the data: no such column: `ESPModules.UnitID`

I am new to sql language and would love some help in formatting this update query correctly.

Thanks

Clan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in [the SQLite `create trigger` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

> the trigger actions may access elements of the row being inserted, deleted or updated using references of the form "NEW.column-name" and "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the name of a column from the table that the trigger is associated with.

So, consider:

```
UPDATE Equipment
SET Last_PMI = date('now'),
Preset_Hrs = 0
WHERE UnitID = NEW.UnitID;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize I had to accept and upvote. Done and thanks again.